# Node error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js

I am creating an app with mongoDB and node.js. In my js file, after I have flashed a message and redirected I get the error "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client":

```
 app.get("/ashanti",function(req,res){
     res.render("regions/ashanti");
 })

 app.post("/ashanti",upload.single("pic"), function(req,res){
     const username=req.body.username;
     const inform=req.body.inform;
     const contact=req.body.contact;
     const region=req.body.region;
     const category=req.body.category;
     const city=req.body.city;
     const community=req.body.community;
     const pic=req.file.path;
     const whatsapp=req.body.whatsapp

     if(req.file){
        console.log(req.file);
     }

     const newuser = new user({
         username:username,
         contact:contact,
         inform:inform,
         region:region,
         category:category,
         community:community,
         city:city,
         pic:pic,
         whatsapp:whatsapp 
     })

     newuser.save().then(function(err,user){
         if(err) throw err
     })

     req.flash("success","post added")
     res.render("regions/ashanti",{success:"success"})
     res.redirect("/navashanti")   
 })
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you have already rendered the page - you've sent a response already. When you attempt to redirect you are sending another response. But **you can only send one response per request**. So you must decide if you want to render the page (`res.render("regions/ashanti",{success:"success"})`) or if you want to redirect (`res.redirect("/navashanti")`).

EDIT: The user asked if it was possible to do both, and this how I suggested it could be possible:

If you absolutely must do both, in the order you have written, you must remove `res.redirect("/navashanti")` from this handler and then in the code that handles the render of `regions/ashanti` you must add your redirect.

Comment: Feel free to update your post above with what you changed and what is not working. The more detail you give the greater the chance someone will be able to help you :)

Comment: It has been upgraded

Comment: You still have a render and a redirect one after another. That will *always* give you the error you are posting about.

Comment: please I still dont get it concerning me adding the redirect to the regions/ashanti route because what I want is to display the flash meassage and upon it being displayed redirect to the /navashanti

Comment: I see. Why have you added this render: `res.render("regions/ashanti",{success:"success"})`? If I understand what you're trying to achieve, you don't need that.

Comment: yeah you see when I dont add the res.render it redirects me with the flash message displayed where it has been redirected but I rather want the flash message before redirecting.Thats the reason for adding the res.render

Comment: I see. That is a different problem, so I would suggest creating a new question to try to help you solve that. However, a quick search brings me to this comment which suggests you call your redirect in a callback of your flash: https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash/issues/23#issuecomment-175730936 Good luck!